# How to format or change a column heading without alter table structures in postgresql using command line

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

I am working on Oracle to PostgreSQL migration. Some .sql files are written to generate reports which is executing in Linux server. Below is code which has to be migrate, Looking for alternate in PostgreSQL.

Ex: In Oracle: test.sql

```
--------------------
col cdmate format 9999999 heading "Code Material"

col cdsorm format A11  heading "Code sort"

select  t.cdmate, t.cdsorm from t_sormat t


Code Material  Code sort
-------------- ---------------------
4832764        Sort-able
```

Comment: @fphilipe: the `psql` tag is correct as the sample code in the question uses special formatting options available in Oracle's `sqlplus` that are applied when the data is displayed - so Manas most probably is looking for a solution in `psql` as well.

Comment: Yes. Oracle's sqlplus giving a lots of formatting options. Few of them have alternative in psql. Is there any way to achieve this format options. (TTITLE LEFT 'Left Headings'  CENTER 'Center Headings' 
SKIP 1   RIGHT ' Right Contents' )

Comment: No, there is no equivalent in `psql` for all those "report formatting" options that are available in SQL\*Plus. Formatting reports is better done in a proper reporting tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use column aliases and the [FORMAT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to get what you need:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT('%-10s', cdmate) AS "Code Material", 
    FORMAT('%-11s', cdsorm) AS "Code Sort"
FROM t_sormat;
```

```
 Code Material |   Code Sort
---------------+-------------
 4832764       | Sort-able
```

Comment: Thanks @Zack for your help. This is one of the alternative we can achieve, but in each query in a .sql file, wherever that the column name is used everywhere I have to use the alias and have to format the columns.  Thanks again for your inputs.

Comment: Hello @Zack, thanks for your help. Could you please tell me how to format this in PostgreSQL. 
{ col col_name format 999,999,990.00 heading " col header name"};

Comment: @ManasMohanty: As noted in the answer, you'll have to use column indexes and the `FORMAT` function. I would try that to get what you need, and post another question if you have issues.